# Extracting the neighbouring cluster to Excel

Tags: qgis, clustering

[image]As a beginner in QGIS, I have a question. I have this [shapefile](https://ibb.co/nftMZCm) which is a map and then divided into clusters. So what I want to do is find the four clusters that share a border with the chosen cluster. So for example, If I pick cluster 91, I would want some kind of automatic process to return cluster 61, 9, 27, and 79. Once, I have these neighbouring clusters then I would want to export the results to excel. Currently, this is a manual process for me but is there a way to automate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use a Virtual layer or Python, there is a built-in tool to achieve what you want.

1. Go to `Menu Vector / Data Management Tools / Join attributes by location` - see screenshot. In the dialog, select twice the same polygon layer: the shapefile with your polygons (or "clusters", as you name it) and check the box `touches`. Than run the tool (if you have many features, it's better to first create a spatial index - see below, point 4):

[image]

2. You get a new polygon layer as output where the attributes of the original layer are doubled (yellow line on the next screenshot). Also your input "clusters" appear several times - as often as the numbers of neighboring "clusters": for each neighbor, you have one entry. On the screenshot, you see an example: CEC76 appears 9 times (red line), each time for each neighbor (turquoise line). So in this case, each attribute EntityHandle is linked to another Entity_Handle_2, corresponding to a neighbor.

[image]

3. To export this to an excel file, right click on your output layer (from 2), select `export /save features as...` and select `MS Office Open XML` or `CSV (comma separated values)` as file format. You get a list containing the same information as visible in the attribute table on the screenshot above.
4. Optimization option: Create a spatial index if your layer contains a larger number of features ("clusters") - than the tool runs faster. To do that, *before* running the tool, use the menu entry `Create Spatial Index` above `Join attributes by location` (first screenshot). Alternative: right click on your original layer, select `properties / source / Create Spatial Index`:

[image]

Comment: This is a brilliant way to go about it and works perfectly. Also, thanks for the detailed explanation as this is so useful to a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a virtual layer and make use of the `group_concat` function to aggregate the neighbors name

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name and field name for yours

```sql
select a.*, group_concat(b.id,'; ') as neighbors_id
from mylayer a
join mylayer b
 on st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
where a.id != b.id
group by a.ID
```

Comment: Apologies if this sounds like an absurd question. I am a complete beginner in QGIS. Could you kindly highlight the fields that I would need to edit? is it just wherever I have 'a' I include my original layer and wherever I have 'b' that would the virtual layer?

Comment: No, just replace "myLayer" with the true name, and the field name "id"